# xarray.open_mfdataset() doesn't work if dask.distributed client has been created

Tags: python, jupyter, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I have a bit of a weird problem that I'd appreciate some input on. Basically, I'm running a notebook on the AWS Pangeo Cloud and am opening some GOES-16 satellite data on S3 (with s3fs) with `xr.open_mfdatase`t.

This works great if I don't use dask at all, the dataset is constructed in a couple minutes.

But if I create a `dask.distributed` client before I open the files, the `open_mfdataset` hangs, seemingly forever.

I made some simple notebooks that can be explored here, as well as a binder link that can be used to run them. Any input would be appreciated!

https://github.com/lsterzinger/pangeo-cloud-L2-satellite/tree/main/dask_troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following achieve what you are after?

```py
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(file_objs, combine='nested', concat_dim='t', data_vars='minimal', coords='minimal', compat='override')
```

Note that the non-dask version loads in about 35 seconds with these settings, while dask one seems to be on the scale of 90 seconds. I haven't worked with this data, so don't know if it's the case here, but it is possible that the scaling advantages will kick-in for a larger number of files (right now it's 24).

This is based on the guidance in the [docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#reading-multi-file-datasets):

> Commonly, a few of these variables need to be concatenated along a dimension (say "time"), while the rest are equal across the datasets (ignoring floating point differences).

> This command concatenates variables along the "time" dimension, but only those that already contain the "time" dimension (data_vars='minimal', coords='minimal'). Variables that lack the "time" dimension are taken from the first dataset (compat='override').